# If $I$ be an ideal of $Z[x]$, then what about $I^n$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Show that if $I$ is the ideal of all polynomials in $Z[x]$ with zero constant term then $I^n= \{a_n x^n +a_{n+1} x^{n+1} +\cdots +a_{n+m} x^{n+m} : a_i\in Z, m\ge 0\}$ is the set of all polynomials whose first non-zero term has degree at least $n$.
I can vizually solve this by taking $I^2$,  $I^3$ but cannot proceed for $n$. Is this can be done by mathematical induction?  Please solve this.

Comment: What are the generators of $I^n$? For an arbitrary generator, expressed as a product, can't you get a factor of $x$ from each factor of the product?

Comment: Can you show $I = (X)$?

Comment: It is obvious that $I=(X)$. @Paul K

Comment: For principal ideals $(a),(b)$ it is easy to see that $(a)(b) = (ab)$.

Comment: Yah sir I have got it. Thank you for your help. It is possible only when the ring is commutative with unity. But I have forgot about unity. @Paul K

Answer (score 1):

$I=x\Bbb Z[x]$ is the principal ideal generated by $x$. Therefore
$I^n=x^n\Bbb Z[x]$ is the principal ideal generated by $x^n$ which
consists of the $f$ with coefficients of $x^j$ zero for $j<n$.

Comment: If $I=xZ[x]$ then we can easily say that $I^n=x^nZ[x]$?  Sir please elaborate me.

Comment: @abcdmath For a principal ideal, $(aR)^n=a^nR$.

Comment: yah. thank you sir I get it. @Lord Shark the Unknown